# PHP textbox math function problems

Tags: php, function, math, plot, expression

i am using the library PHPLOT, which can plot math expressions with 1 variable in a X/Y axis system.

i have a text box that where the user can input a math function, ex. sin(x)
in order for phplot to work, i need to replace sin(x) with sin($x) so i can enter my own variables and make it plot.
currently I'm using this to decide the values to plot:

```
for ($x = $startX; $x <= $endX; $x += $delta) {
    $func2 = str_replace("x",$x,$func);
    $data[] = array('', $x, $func2);}
```

but nothing is plotted, if instead of $func2 i enter sin($x) i will get the plot.

```
for ($x = $startX; $x <= $endX; $x += $delta) {
    $data[] = array('', $x, sin($x);}
```

how do i make php replace x with $x and still see it as math...

Comment: And whats the value of `$func`

Answer (score 1):

You need to eval `$func2`

```
$data[] = array('', $x, eval($func2))
```

Anyway, running eval on something that the user inputs in a form is not a very good idea. Maybe you should try using [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).